# How to print out atoi value

Tags: c

I try to print out the `atoi` value from the function that is shown in The C Programming Language but I found out that the previous format for main cant print out the `atoi` value.

Previously, I have write `htoi` in C with this format but this time it don't work. The code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int get_line(char line[], int maxline);
int atoi(char s[]);                                                                                                                                                                                                  

int main(void)
{
    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = get_line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        atoi(line);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_line(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n, sign;

    for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++)
        ;
    sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-')
        i++;
    for (n = 0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');

    return sign * n;
}
```

It copy the user's input instead of print out the int value converted by `atoi` which is not my desired result.

Comment: You call `atoi` without saving the result, and then you print the inputted line. What did you expect? Even if you actually print the converted integer, the result will be exactly the same as your input.

Comment: `line` is the input to atoi

Comment: Why are you re-implementing [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)?

Comment: Works for me. VTC until actual problem appears.

Comment: @chux I want convert s into integer and then display the integer

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of `atoi()` to a variable and print that.

```
    while ((len = get_line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        int num = atoi(line);
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
```

Comment: is it normal if when I input character but the `atoi` only return 0?

Comment: It's normal if you enter something that isn't a number.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in your code, atoi returns an int. At that point you have two solutions :
A . You store the returned value in a variable then you print it.
B . You print it without storing it using :

```
printf("%d",atoi(string));
```

Note : if you weren't aware of its existence, there is a already a function atoi() in stdlib.h.

Comment: actually i just want to learn the way how K&R write `atoi` function without using `<stdlib.h>`